# Performance of searching a number in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing some tests about finding a number in a number array with python. With the following code,

```
from time import time
search = 9999999
numbers = []
for i in range(100000000):
    numbers.append(i)

start_time = time()
is_in = search in numbers
end_time = time()
print(is_in, end_time - start_time)
```

I got the output as follows:

```
True 0.10372281074523926
```

However, the amount of time that has passed seems much more than the output (nearly 4 seconds). In addition to that, when I change the `search` value to 0, it outputs the following,

```
True 0.0
```

But still, the amount of time that the program needs to terminate is nearly 4-5 seconds, (measured by human instincs) I wonder what is the reason behind this. Why it does not finish after 0.1 seconds as measured and why searching for 0 results in 0.0 seconds?

Comment: There is an overhead to start up and tear down the interpreter, but most of the time of your program is probably spent filling the `numbers` list. You may consider using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module for more effective time bechmarking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long do you think it takes to build your `numbers` list, specially when doing so in the most inefficient way ? Well, let's check it - but let's check it the right way: using timeit:

```
>>> def foo():
...     l = []
...     for i in range(100000000): l.append(i)
...     return l
... 
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("foo()", "from __main__ import foo", number=1)
6.561729616951197
```

So on this desktop (which is a rather decent machine), just creating this list already takes 6.5 seconds.

Now let's test the linear search:

```
>>> def search(i, num):
...    return i in num
... 
>>> numbers = foo()
>>> timeit.timeit("search(9999999, numbers)", "from __main__ import search, numbers", number=1)
0.06766342208720744
```

So we need 6.5 seconds to build the list, and 0.067 seconds to do a linear search. Note that in both cases we only executed the code under test one single time (the `number=1` argument to `timeit`), which is not really accurate due to os process scheduling. For a more accurate reading you want to repeat the operation thousands times or more (the default value is actually 1000000 !) so you get a reasonably representative average value.

Now just for the fun let's rewrite `foo()`:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return list(range(100000000))
... 
>>> timeit.timeit("foo()", "from __main__ import foo", number=1)
2.594872738001868
```

That's still long, but it's about 2.5 times faster. If you wonder why:  this waythe runtime can allocate the required memory for the full list right from the start instead of having to grow it again and again and again.

And for a much more efficient (and constant time !) search:

```
>>> numset = set(numbers)
>>> timeit.timeit("search(9999999, numset)", "from __main__ import search, numset", number=1)
3.505963832139969e-06
```

Wait !!! 3.5 something seconds ??? But no - notice the `e-06` at the end, it's actually 0.00000350596383213996 seconds, so almost 20000 times faster.

Comment: Thank you for such a explanatory answer. Now I know the correct way to measure execution time. But one more thing, back in my code, when I call the start_time = time(), process of creating a list with huge amount of elements if already finished right? So why should I worry about creation time after for loop is finished. I thought in the rest of the code I was measuring the execution time of search in numbers statement.

Comment: Yes you are indeed only measuring the search time itself - but the mere notion of "time" is not necessarily that trivial when it comes to the execution time of a code snippet. The doc mentions those caveats and points to some references